# Select 5 of each distinct value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following table in PostgreSQL:

```
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
===================
| 'w' |  2  |  3  |
| 'w' |  7  |  2  |
| 'w' |  8  |  1  |
| 'w' |  3  |  6  |
| 'w' |  0  |  8  |
| 'w' |  2  |  9  |
| 'w' |  2  |  9  |
| 'z' |  4  |  9  |
| 'z' |  0  |  9  |
| 'z' |  0  |  8  |
| 'z' |  3  |  6  |
| 'z' |  2  |  7  |
| 'z' |  3  |  1  |
| 'z' |  3  |  2  |
| 'z' |  3  |  3  |
```

I want to select all records, but limit them to 5 records for each distinct value in column `a`.
So the result would look like:

```
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
===================
| 'w' |  2  |  3  |
| 'w' |  7  |  2  |
| 'w' |  8  |  1  |
| 'w' |  3  |  6  |
| 'w' |  0  |  8  |
| 'z' |  4  |  9  |
| 'z' |  0  |  9  |
| 'z' |  0  |  8  |
| 'z' |  3  |  6  |
| 'z' |  2  |  7  |
```

What is the most effecient way to achieve that in RoR? Thanks!

Comment: [If one of the below answer solve your problem, kindly mark it as the right answer, see here how](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 3):

you can use [row_number](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-window.html), but you have to specify order or you will get unpredictable resutls

```
   with cte as (
       select
           *,
           row_number() over(partition by a order by b, c) as row_num
       from table1
   )
   select a, b, c
   from cte
   where row_num <= 5
```